# what are the algorithm differences between JPEG and GIF?

Tags: multimedia

I am currently doing an assigment and cannot find the answer to this question..as Algorithm is supposed to mean (solving problems as such)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference is that JPEG uses a lossy algorithm, and GIF uses a losless algorithm (LZW). In addition, GIF is limited to 256 colors, while JPEG is truecolor (8 bits per color per pixel)

Comment: It's limited to a 256 color *palette*, not 256 colors. GIF uses 24-bit colors.

Comment: GIF isn't necessarily limited to 256 colors. It's only limited to 256 colors per image block, and most GIFs only use one block.

http://phil.ipal.org/tc.html

Comment: Thanks very much its after helping alot with my assignment!!

Answer (score 2):

[Some info is here](http://www.siriusweb.com/tutorials/gifvsjpg/).

Basically, JPEG is good for real life images, and GIF is good for computer generated images with solid areas or when you need some text to not be blurred  (JPEG is lossy, GIF is not). There are many other differences too.

See also Wikipedia:

[GIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format)

[JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jpeg)

For bonus points in your assignment you might want to mention other commonly used standards such as [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics).

Answer (score 1):

i found a very good web site that explains about the difference between gif and jpeg plus it shows image examples of several scenarios. enjoy.

http://www.siriusweb.com/tutorials/gifvsjpg/